# How to exclude from a contains query all the informations from a child class & after some sibling text?

Tags: xpath, contains, siblings

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <a></a>
  <d></d>
  <e></e>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</root>
```

In an XML document, how can I exclude from a contains research all the information from nodes after <d> ?

to get only result from:

```
<a></a>
 <b></b>
 <c></c>
 <a></a>
 <d></d>
```

I can't say only the first 2 answer from

and first for

and <c> because sometimes a value will exist only after the <d>

I have this code that is working:

```
//div[contains(@class,'class searched')]/*[contains(text(), 'Text Searched')] | //div[contains(@class,'class searched')]/*[not(contains(@class,'class excluded'))]/*[contains(text(), 'Text Searched')]
```

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT for clarity:

```
<div Class="TopClass">
    <div Class="ClassA">
        <div Class="ClassB">
        <h3> Text Researched</h3>
            <u1 Class="ClassC">
                <h3> Text Researched</h3>
            </u1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Other Text</h4>
    <div Class="ClassA">
        <div Class="ClassB">
        <h3> Text Researched</h3>
            <u1 Class="ClassC">
                <h3> Text Researched</h3>
            </u1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to get only the Text Researched that is between the Class B and Class C and that is above the "Other Text". Sometime the "Text researched" will only appear below the "Other Text" and i don't want to get this result so a [1] will not work there. Also the `<h3>` and `<h4>` are used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking but this xpath will get all up to d included: `//d[following-sibling::e] | //d[following-sibling::e]/preceding-sibling::*` which reads "the node itself and its preceding siblings". Try to add a sample that matches your tested XPaths.

Comment: I will try to be clearer, in the <d> there is some text and i would like the code to stop the query when it get to this text, so i tried to add this at the end of my code without success:

/*[not(following-sibling::d(.='Keyword'))]

Comment: The answer depends a lot on the input so try to change your xml sample to represent your use case.

Comment: I edited my post to give more code and explaination about my differents constraint. 
I don't know how to code so this thing is pretty new to me. I managed to exclude the result below the "ClassC" but probably not the most efficient way to do it so i'm interested by the full solution and explainations :)

I guess we could use position with a value determined by the position of "Other Text".

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry to insist but the html sample has no closing tags so it's not possible to determine if elements are siblings, children, etc. Xpath depends on concrete samples many times.

Comment: Sorry i thought the closing tag were obvious, i added them to the codeblock. 
If you want to take a look at the real application:
shorturl.at/ntI78

I want to get for any decklist of this website the number of Creatures, Enchantment etc in the mainboard of a decklist without what is in the maybeboard. I also remove the text from the cards name because some card might include "Land" etc... in their name.

In the code structure above vs real application:
TopClass=Well
ClassA=row board-container
ClassB=board-col col-md-4 col-sm-12
ClassC=boardlist

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this html

```
<div class="TopClass">
    <div class="ClassA">
        <div class="ClassB">
        <h3> Text Researched 1</h3>
            <u1 class="ClassC">
                <h3> Text Researched 2</h3>
            </u1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Other Text</h4>
    <div class="ClassA">
        <div class="ClassB">
        <h3> Text Researched 3</h3>
            <u1 class="ClassC">
                <h3> Text Researched 4</h3>
            </u1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This XPath expression will get the first 2 `h3` tags
`//div[@class="ClassA" and following-sibling::h4[.="Other Text"]]//h3[contains(.,"Text Researched 1")]/text()`

Result:

```
echo -e 'cat //div[@class="ClassA" and following-sibling::h4[.="Other Text"]]//h3/text()\nbye' | xmllint --shell test.html 
/ > cat //div[@class="ClassA" and following-sibling::h4[.="Other Text"]]//h3[contains(.,"Text Researched 1")]/text()
 -------
 Text Researched 1
/ > bye
```

Comment: Actually in the real application there is several <h3> below the class B (each with u1...) with various texts and i would like to be able to query the one i want so i would like to be able to add [contains(text(), 'Text Researched 1')] 

And i also would like to not get the "Text Researched 2" in my results.

Comment: Added your expected filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! You were really patient and helpful :)

Comment: You can accept the answer if you want :-)